# Disable CTRL + ALT + F5 shortcut

Tags: xfce, xubuntu

How can I disable the global <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (terminal login) shortcut in Xubuntu?

Tried Window Manager settings, LightDM settings and Keyboard settings.

Comment: I tried  [this](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/es-es/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/desktop_migration_and_administration_guide/disable-command-line-access) on VM with Ubuntu. Does that work for you? In the section "Disabling Virtual Terminal Switching"

Comment: Basically you have to create a file under '/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-xorg.conf' and paste this: "Section "Serverflags"

Option "DontVTSwitch" "yes"

EndSection"

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick

Comment: @EdgarMagallon please don't answer in comments. That just leaves the question unanswered for ever, and the answer cannot be voted on.

Comment: @terdon oh sure! I was going to answer the question and before that, I was thinking about searching a similar question in this forum but I had to leave for some hours.